Error Factory.Domain.FetchInstance(connection, null, null) in c# not connect
I am trying to connect to the FileNet server with Factory.Domain.FetchInstance(connection, null, null) and it generates an error:

Por favor me pueden colaborar.

The program runs fine, but when it executes the instruction
Factory.Domain.FetchInstance(connection, null, null);
generates the following errors

A network error occurred when processing a Web service request or response. See the nested exception for specific details.'
AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is not valid according to the validation procedure.


A network error occurred when processing a Web service request or response. See the nested exception for specific details.'
WebException: Connection has been terminated: A trust relationship cannot be established for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
Server connection error. It appears that Visual Studio 2022 Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) is not running on the remote computer.
This may be because a Firewall prevents communication with the remote computer.


The error explains itself. In other words, the remote certificate is not trusted. It might be a self signed developer certificate for developing purposes only. Or maybe the certificate is expired.
However, you may disable certificate validation like in the first line in code below:
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain,
errors) => true;
=Factory.Domain.FetchInstance(connection, null, null); 


Thank you very much for your cooperation. I inserted the code that you told me and now it indicates
"The user has not been authenticated." Do you know how I can validate the user directly.
